Name resolution fails within script, but works as singular command
I'm really confused here. Here's my script. If this script finds 3 machines (for example), I'll get an error that test-netconnection failed to resolve the name on two of them and one will work. If for any of them, I step through and get the exact string that the commmand is running and run that manually, it always works.
$MachineGroupFile = Get-ChildItem c:\scripts\temp\ -Filter *.txt
$MachineGroupFile | where-object Name -match "^1930.*" | ForEach-Object {
   Get-Content $_ | Sort-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object {
       test-netconnection $_
   }
}

Any idea what could be going wrong here?
By the way, I don't care about running test-netconnection. That's just standing in for the command that I actually want to run which was failing due to name resolution.

Inside your foreach-object try something like write-host “value = ‘$_’”; write-host “length = $($_.Length)”, then check the length of the string looks correct - you might have some non-printing characters hiding in the strings that you aren’t reproducing when you run the commands manually…

I thought I had checked for that, but mclayton was right. I had a space at the end of my $_ variable. Even though the command would work fine typing it in with a space at the end (or doing a copy/paste of what is on the screen), specifying it in a variable seems to cause everything in that variable to go into the computer name argument, rather than parsing out the whole line as text.
I fixed that by either fixing my source or using $_.trim().

When you log output to the console it’s often a good idea to include delimiters around the value (like the apostrophes in my comment) so you can see if there’s extra spaces at the end - that’s saved me from hours of debugging more times than I can remember :-).
